# Parsing and presenting Data from Ganglia

Tags: ganglia

I have just started using ganglia.

I am getting data from the clients on the ganglia frontend and Graphs too.

But the data I am getting is raw. it is appearing like key value on the frontend.

Is there any tool with which I can parse it and present as a dashboard ?

The data I am getting is mostly system configuration and performance

Regards,

W

Comment: Can you be a little more explanative in your question

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back. I moved on to a different setup. I was trying to monitor QNAP devices using ganglia. I am getting the data using gmetad client to my cental ganglia server. But the data is kind of raw.So, I was hoping to see if I can find a way to parse it in anyway. I am not a programmer myself, but wanted to understand if there are any tools

Comment: Using Graphite and Grafana works wonderfully and I made it work.